# datagridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите с кодом. Мне нужно при выборе столбца/столбцов в одном datagridview передавать этот столбец/столбцы в другой datagridview. Как такое можно реализовать, через какое событие. Может есть какой пример

Comment: для графического компонента DataGridView задается источник данных (DataSource). источником данных может быть DataTable, либо List. Если вы из источника данных одного компонента перенесете столбцы в другой источник, то в другом компоненте эти столбцы появятся автоматически. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402324/copy-specific-columns-from-one-datatable-to-another)

Comment: не уверен, что у компонента есть возможность выбирать весь столбец. наверное только ячейку, тогда напрашивается использование события CellClick. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642617/datagridview-row-header-click-giving-last-selected-columns-index)